# How to check a list for a different instance of a class inheriting generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a `List<ICar<T>>` cars.  I want to add new `ICar<T>` Honda to the list only if it does not already exist in there.  The structure is like:

```
class Honda : IHonda{}
interface IHonda : ICar<T>

class Ford  : IFord{}
interface IFord  : ICar<T>
```

I only want to put one of each type of car into the list, but only knowing that they are `ICar<T>`.  I don't know ahead of time the list of possible cars.  How can this be done?

I was thinking something like

```
cars.Any(i => i.GetType().GetInterfaces().Contains(
                    car
                    .GetType()
                    .GetInterfaces()
                    .Where(s =>!cars.GetType().GenericTypeArguments != s.GenericTypeArguments
))))
```

However, something is wrong with that and I can't quite see a path through this one.

Comment: cars.Any(c=>c.GetType().FullName == car.GetType().FullName); Worked like a champ.  Thanks all for helping me out of the rabbit hole :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Type` instance corresponding to `T` then you can use:

```
Type t = //
Type carType = typeof(ICar<>).MakeGenericType(t);
bool exists = cars.Any(c => carType.IsAssignableFrom(c.GetType()));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know T up front.

Comment: @JohnS. - By 'know T up front' I mean you have a `Type` variable containing `T`, which I assume is `s` in your example?

Comment: s is one of several possible interfaces the object may be implementing (e.g. IFord, ICar<T>).  T is a different object all together.

Comment: @JohnS. - Ok, well you must have the type for `T` somewhere, otherwise what are you looking for? I assume you have a car you want to add to the list, so you can get `t` from there. Otherwise you could use a dictionary instead of a list keyed on the car type.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use

```
 //get list of all interfaces in the currrent car list
 //you will have to check the contents of yourList as it may contain some types 
 //such as IList / IEnumerable that you will want to filter out.
 var yourList =  list.SelectMany(car => car.GetType().GetInterfaces());

 //check get all interfaces on your car and check if the list contains it
 bool exists = yourCar.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(c => yourList.Contains(c));
```

Comment: How do you get the "yourTypeToCheck" if I only want to check if it s Ford or IFord, but not check to see if it is ICar<T> (since they all are)?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to compare the elements using the fully qualified name of the type.

```
CarTypeComparer compareCarTypes = new CarTypeComparer();

if (!List.contains(car, compareCarTypes))
{
   // insert car into list
}

class CarTypeComparer : IEqualityComparer<ICar<T>>
{
   public bool Equals(ICar<T> car1, ICar<T> car2)
   {
      if (car1.GetType().FullName == car2.GetType().Fullname)
      {
          return true;
      }
      else 
      {
          return false;
      }

   }
   // implement GetHashCode() ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a CarModel property inside of your ICar interface,and then implement it in your classes.For example in Honda class:

```
public string CarModel { get { return "Honda"; } }
```

you can check CarModel property in your query and ofcourse you can group your cars by CarModel,i hope this helps..